# Searching for a mod to Diablo II: Lord Of Destruction that features the song, "I Am A Viking" by Yngwie Malmsteen

Tags: mods, diablo-ii, mod-identification

I'm trying to find a mod for *Diablo II: LoD* which I played a few years ago on a friend's laptop. This friend doesn't remember the name of the mod. The problem is that I have very limited information which can help me to find it.

The first thing that I remember from this mod is the theme music. The original music was replaced by a nice rock theme: **"Yngwie Malmsteen - I Am A Viking"**.

Second thing that I remember is that all stats (weapon, armor, and skills ) were raised.

Third and the last thing that I remember was that the "Den of Evil" only contained Diablo (many of them) so after finishing the normal game you can back from nightmare and go there and farm some EQ.

That's all I know. Does anyone know what mod this is?

Comment: Since you don't have any media (sound clips, screenshots, etc), game identification questions (or even mods) without this information are deemed off-topic here. There are lots of mods that allow outside music in games, and that raise stats, so we'd just be guessing here.

Comment: Ok so flag it. If i had some Screanshots i will post it but i don't have. I have no other infromation. Also i don't know how many mods come to LoD. Just tough that was unique and someone recognize it

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open as it does have some artifacts from the mod in question - the new music theme and the base game.

Comment: Please note that a lot of mods are now broken because Blizzard just released patch 1.14. There hasn't been a new patch released in almost 6 years, so a lot of mod development has stopped and the makers of these mods have not released anything for 1.14 yet.

Comment: I'm casting a reopen vote as there are clear artifacts from the game and this is absolutely not a recommendation question in any way shape or form.

Comment: @ChaseC, not necessarily, it is quite easy to install a specific version of Diablo 2. Last time I played a mod (5+ years ago) most didn't even support the newest patch.

Comment: About the only artifact we have here is a music track.  That can, I suppose, meet the requirements for an artifact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mod is called Valhalla, here is the splash screen where **"I Am a Viking"** plays:

[image: Valhalla Splash screen]

This image was pulled from [www.moddb.com/mods/valhalla](http://www.moddb.com/mods/valhalla) which also seems like the best place to get the mod these days; I believe it used to be hosted on Phrozen Keep